# Ctrl-N in emacs keybindings for Jupyter notebook in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, jupyter-notebook

I'm using Jupyter notebooks in the Chrome browser. I've installed nbextensions and am using the emacs keybindings. Most keys work as expected, even those that conflict with Chrome shortcuts, like ctrl-P. But ctrl-N still opens a new window. I've tried Shortkeys, with which I can set ctrl-N to "do nothing", but it is not passed through to the notebook. I tried AutoControl Shortcut Manager and have the same problem.

Old answers to this question say that you can't override ctrl-N at all, which is no longer true in the newer versions of Chrome, but how do you stop the default behavior and allow the key to pass through to the page?

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with [AutoControl Shortcut Manager](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/autocontrol-shortcut-mana/lkaihdpfpifdlgoapbfocpmekbokmcfd) by using the **<kbd>SYNTHESIZE INPUT</kbd>** action to send a synthetic **Ctrl**+**N** from the inside of the webpage.

That way, the webpage will respond to the shortcut but not the browser.

This is how you do it: [image: Send Ctrl+N from inside webpage]

1. Set <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> as the trigger
2. Choose <kbd>SYNTHESIZE INPUT</kbd> as the action and enter the keystroke **Ctrl**+**N**
3. Select option **Send from the inside of webpage**

Now, whenever you press Ctrl+N, Chrome will do nothing, but the webpage will receive the keystroke and will react to it.

Of course, you'd only want to do this on those Jupyter Notebook pages, so make sure you add a URL condition to that trigger.

Comment: I tried this and I'm still getting a new Chrome window popping up. [Here's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ROEOY.jpg) what I entered. i deliberately left out the URL part so their no ambiguity about not matching the URL.

Comment: @Llaves, your synthetic input sequence is wrong. You are releasing **Ctrl** before and after **N**. Change the first **Ctrl** to PRESS instead of RELEASE. Also, on the Trigger side, make sure you are overriding the **N**.

Comment: That solved it. Not sure how I managed to enter left-ctrl-release both times, but knowing what to watch for, I was able to get it right. Thanks.